# If statement not calling function

Tags: python, if-statement

For some reason my if statement won't do what it is meant to do. I am not sure as to why as i'm sure that I have formatted it correctly.

```
def attack():
    os.system('clear')
    pAttack=random.randint(playerIG.attack/2, playerIG.attack)
    eAttack=random.randint(enemy.attack/2, enemy.attack)
    if pAttack==playerIG.attack/2:
        print "You miss!"
    else:
        enemy.health-=pAttack
        print "You deal %s damage" % pAttack
    option=raw_input("")
    if enemy.health<=0:
        win()
    os.system('clear')
    if eAttack==enemy.attack/2:
        print "The enemy missed!"
    else:
        playerIG.health-=eAttack
        print "The enemy deals %s damage" % eAttack
    option=raw_input("")
    if playerIG.health<=0:
        die()
    else:
        fight()
```

The part we are looking at is:

```
if enemy.health<=0:
        win()
```

I'm not sure why but it won't call win() even when the enemy health is below zero.

Win function:

```
def win():
    print "You have successfully killed the %s!" % enemy.name
    print "You have gained %s gold!" % enemy.goldgain
```

Any solution will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: How do you know that `enemy.health<=0`?

Comment: By asking, if enemy.health<=0? I have the same code for player health and it works fine goes to the die() function. Not sure why the enemy health won't work.

Comment: What I mean is: your observation is that the if statement is not being executed. The simplest explanation would be that `enemy.health` never goes below 0.

Comment: It does though.  As it prints the enemies health, enemy.health, and it prints -10/100. -10 health out of 100 health.

Comment: okay, great. That's exactly what I was asking. From the question, it's not clear whether you checked. There's no statement printing the health in the code. But clearly you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called `os.system('clear')` immediately after `win()`, so you won't see the win message.